# Using MythTV to Stream Satellite Signal to multiple users

Tags: video, streaming, mythtv, satellite

I'm planning on setting up a small media center to achieve the following:

1. I have multiple users who want to watch satellite channels

   I want them to be able to change the channel remotely

   I'm going to buy an external DVB to capture the signal

   Use some software to stream the channel that is selected

   I want to have 2 different channels at the same time, I assume I will need two DVB cards

   Users use VLC or Windows Media Player or whatever to view the channels

How can I achieve this? I heard MythTV can do it? I tried to do some research I couldn't find enough information.

**Note:** There's no copyright issue here. I'm streaming Free-To-Air (FTA) channels.

Answer (score 2):

MythTV will do this for you (this is basically what MythTV is for), but to meet all your requirements you would need to run MythTV on all the clients.  MythTV operates in a client-server mode; the server (or "backend") is the device that actually has the DVBs.  The clients ("frontends") run the GUI and allow the users to watch recorded programs, live tv, schedule new recordings, etc.

You can use VLC to watch pre-recorded video from the myth server, but you can't use it to watch live tv, see the program guide, change channels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't know any of this, but with the info you provided I did some googling, I think you will find this info helpfull.

http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/voip/streaming-live-tv.asp

http://www.ethics-gradient.net/myth/mythdvb.html

http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Configuring_HDTV